# data-dojo-props and quotes

Tags: jsp, dojo, jstl, el

I'm trying to set an icon dynamically in a tabcontainer. This example works fine

```
<div id="tab3" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props='title:"Tab 3",
iconClass:"dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconSave", closable:true'>
```

But I'm using JSTL/Spring Roo, and I generate the CSS class dynamically (so I can have different images on each tab).

When I try this

```
data-dojo-props='title:"Tab 3", iconClass:"${person.iconClass}", closable:true'
```

...and then view the source, something is adding extra double quotes, and it doesn't render at all.

The working example somehow converts the double quotes to " escaped versions.

Help!

Comment: What does `Person.getIconClass()` do?

Comment: It returns a String, which could be something to do with the quotes. It'll return a string like "adminClass" or "userClass" which matches up with a css definition elsewhere. Pretty sure the strings themselves don't contain quotes (I'll double check). It's as if the expression evaluation is somehow going a bit wrong.

Comment: There isn't anything obviously wrong in the code you've posted and the Expression Language won't insert quotes into expression results (unless you've added some really funny EL plugin.) Are you inspecting the raw page data served via HTTP or the live DOM after Dojo has run its parser over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to McDowell for the tips. I got it working in the end simply by changing the single quotes and double quotes around. I copied the example above from the internet somewhere, and ran into problems, but changing it to

```
data-dojo-props="title:'Tab 3', iconClass:'${person.iconClass}', closable:true"
```

seemed to do the trick.

Turns out I can't have my own icons anyway (there are a set of predefined ones you can only choose from as far as I can tell) but it was a good learning excercise :)